# Bootstrap 5 nav bar dropdown not showing up when toaster is added in the page

Tags: dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5, toast, angular14

[dropdown not showing the list on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuvft.png)

When click on login, it is successfully showing the toast message. But Nav bar drop down is not showing the dropdown list when click.
If remove the  from this page. dropdwon working fine.
[toast is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yrgb.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
         ** <a class="nav-link" href="#"  (click)="login()">Login</a>    **
**This is showing the toast messages **
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
**<app-toaster></app-toaster>**
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I fixed it by regenerated the angular project using ng new <project_name>. then instead of npm install bootstrap, I used ng cli command - ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, which installed all the necessary dependencies in angular.json and package.json. It started working.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with Vue3